How to run mysql on mac os?
I installed mysql using brew:
brew install mysql

Installation went fine without any error.
When I do:
brew services

I see:
mysql none

Seems mysql is not started.
So how to get it running?

brew services start mysql if you want it to start now, and automatically start after a reboot; or mysql.server start if you just want to start it now.

This question is similar to: How do you stop MySQL on a Mac OS install?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you can also download a DMG package directly from MySQL.
This includes directly the installer.
Nothing else to do.
